# Displaying a table as a matrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

For my ASP.Net MVC web application, I have some objects of classA which need to be referenced to every object of classA, including itself, and each connection needs another object of classB. I've stored all these objects in other objects from classC. All this data is stored in a database.

This gives me a huge list, larger the more objects from classA there are, because when I add a new object of classA, this table needs to be updated, though this is not part of the question.

Now I want to display this table but as a matrix.

I have:

```html
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Object 1 (classA)</th>
        <th>Object 2 (classA)</th>
        <th>Value (classB)</th>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>value1</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>QWER</td>
        <td>value2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

I want:

```html
    <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td/>
            <th>Object 1 (classA)</th>
            <th>Object 2 (classA)</th>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Object 1 (classA)</th>
            <td>value1</td>
            <td>value2</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
              <th>Object 2 (classA)</th>
            <td>value2</td>
            <td>value1</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

My problem is, that I can't just iterate over all entries in my current table and display it on my HTML page, since it would be redundant (and therefor huge) as hell.

My question now is, how can I display my data as I want?
I've looked for similar questions but none of what I found were using the same class twice.

**EDIT**
I may not have been precise with my description. Here are my classes (shortened):

```
public class classA {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class classB {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
}

public class classC {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual classA PersonA {get; set;}
    public virtual classA PersonB {get; set;}
    public virtual classB friendship {get; set;}
}
```

So there is no object stored in classA, only in classC which I then use to Display the data in HTML.

Comment: How does you data look like? What about your SQL query? Are you looking to join two different tables?

Comment: @silkfire My data class (classC) has 3 properties: `public virual ClassA row { get; set;}` `public virual ClassA column { get; set;}` and `public virual ClassB value { get; set;}`. I currently use lazy loading for my HTML page and I use only one table for my data, no joins. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Could you please post the defination of your classA, classB and classC? As far as I have understood is that classA references itself and classB, whereas classC holds the list of classA.
Putting the dummy names in a context do you mean this:

public class Person // classA    {
        
        public Person Friend { get; set; }
        public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address // classB
    {
        public string StreetName { get; set; }  
    }

    public class People // classC
    {
        public IList<Person> PersonList { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @YawarMurtaza - I edited my question. I noticed that my classB only has 1 value, so I could make it an enum in classC... But this doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite a proper answer since I needed to do a bit more...

I created a ViewModel where I'll store all data I needed:

```
// ViewModel
public List<classA> PersonA {get; set;}
public List<classA> PersonB {get; set;}
public List<classC> Rels {get; set;}
```

and then add it in the controller:

```
RelsViewModel vieModel = new RelsViewModel();
viewModel.Rels = db.Rels.ToList();

List<classA> personsA = new List<classA>();
List<classA> personsB = new List<classA>();
foreach (classA item in db.Rels.ToList())
{
    personsA.Add(item.PersonA);
    personsB.Add(item.PersonB);
}

// Distinct() Returns the list without duplicates
viewModel.personsA = personsA.Distinct().ToList();
viewModel.personsB = personsB.Distinct().ToList();

return View(viewModel);
```

In the HTML I then looped through each personA for the head row:

```
@model ZoneMatrix.ViewModel.MatrixViewModel

...

<tr>
    <th>Name</th> @*most top left cell*@
    @foreach (var item in Model.PersonsA)
    {
        <th>@item.name</th>
    }
</tr>

...
```

and then one loop through all personB with a loop through all personA nested inside. PersonsA is the exact same as PersonsB, so you can check if your matrix table (column PersonB) contains the id from item (type classB) and in column PersonA contains item2's id (type classA). If so, return the friendship property:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PersonsB)
{
    <tr>
        <th>@item.name</th>
        @foreach (var item2 in Model.PersonsA)
        {
            <td>
                @(Model.Rels.Where(i => i.PersonsB.Id == item.Id && i.PersonsA.Id == item2.Id).SingleOrDefault().friendship.Value)
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

Shout out to @Aldracor for his help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to get a distinct list of persons, eg :

```
        var rels = new classC[] { new classC { Id = 11, PersonA = new classA { Id = 1, Name = "one" }, PersonB = new classA { Id = 1, Name = "one" }, friendship = new classB { Id = 11, Value = "1-1" } }
                                , new classC { Id = 12, PersonA = new classA { Id = 1, Name = "one" }, PersonB = new classA { Id = 2, Name = "two" }, friendship = new classB { Id = 12, Value = "1-2" } }
                                , new classC { Id = 21, PersonA = new classA { Id = 2, Name = "two" }, PersonB = new classA { Id = 1, Name = "one" }, friendship = new classB { Id = 21, Value = "2-1" } }
                                , new classC { Id = 22, PersonA = new classA { Id = 2, Name = "two" }, PersonB = new classA { Id = 2, Name = "two" }, friendship = new classB { Id = 22, Value = "2-2" } }
        };

        List<classA> persons;
        if (rels.Any())
        {
            persons = rels.GroupBy(r => r.PersonA.Id)
                            .Select(g => g.First())
                            .Select(r => r.PersonA)
                            .ToList(); // gets a distinc list, you might want to order this too
        }
```

Then in your view create loops through each person for the `<th>`'s (*perB*) then your loop for your `<tr>` (*perA*) with nested loops for each relevant `<td>` (*perB*). Then in your nested loop you just select the `friendship.Value` eg:

```
<td>
    @(Model.rels.Where(r=> r.PersonA.Id == perA.Id && r.PersonB.Id == perB.Id).SingleOrDefault()?.friendship?.Value)
<td>
```

**(you might have to add `@using System.Linq` to your view)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now my first row and my first column are displayed correctly (each entry once) :) ! But your line for the HTML doesn't work for me because I don't have the array of rels in my controller but sets in my database. I have `public virtual ICollection<classC> Rels { get; set; }` in my classA but it seems to be empty when I debug the project in the HTML doc. Any idea on how I get to access the database from my model (classA) ?

Comment: @MarcoHabegger Use the same `Model` and method you used to produce your first table in your question. Otherwise read up here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/769/getting-started-with-asp-net-mvc#t=201612221237393075253

Comment: @Taysumi Why do you need to access `classC` from `classA`? Create a Model that contains `List<classC> Rels {get; set;}` and `List<classA> Persons {get; set;}` and then use that instead.

Comment: I now created a ViewModel where I loaded all the data I needed and could finish the HTML with your code. Thank you very much ! :)